# Asp.net membership provider, login name\status

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to learn - how the login status or login name from the login wizard (asp.net membersip provider) know who is connected now. how it's know to display my name if i'm connected? it's work by stored procedure? if yes - how exactly?

I want to learn that for my project. i'm trying to display "accaount details" for costumer - when he click on the button of "account details" he will get only his details. i know to work with LINQ and query strings, but it's not the same for this. so i think that if i will understand the login name , i will know how to do my project.

I've seen the asp.net membership stored-procedure, and i tried to learned from the northwind database because they put there "order details" , but i don't get the idea - how it get the userId..

Hope the question is clear. maybe I just completely lost my concentration and it's so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ScottGu's Membership Tutorial Series](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/06/19/ASP.NET-2.0-Security_2C00_-Membership-and-Roles-Tutorials.aspx).  You probably won't need to read the complete series, but certainly part 1 will get you off on the right foot.

Answer (score 0):

May be you will also find useful reading another [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs) on the same topic (especially starting from Step 2: Enabling Forms Authentication).